# How to create a checkbox that goes to a certain link under specific conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

So I am trying to create a function in which I have various checkboxes of territories. The only thing is that I have pages for only some of the territories. So when a user selects a territory and it has a link to a page, then on submit it will take the user to that page. If the checkbox does not have a link then it will go to contact page. But if they select more than one territory and one of them has a link, it should still take them to that same contact page. The second part is that I want the selections to be parsed to the url to go to the contact page which will be a contact form 7 form so it auto fills the territory they selected.

so far I have created a function which recognizes how many checkboxes have been selected. I tried to add links and identify if those links that were selected with the checkbox. Im not sure if it is recognizing it with its corresponding element.

Html

```
<a href="https://corporate.territory.place/advertising-sandiego" 
id="salesURL"><input type="checkbox" name="territories" value="San 
Diego, CA">San Diego, CA</a>
<a href="https://corporate.territory.place/advertising-orlando" 
id="salesURL"><input type="checkbox" name="territories" 
value="Orlando, FL">Orlando, FL</a>
<a href="#" id="nosalesURL"><input type="checkbox" 
name="territories" value="Miami, FL">Miami, FL</a><br>
<button onclick="printChecked()">Click here</button>
```

jquery

```
function printChecked(){
var items=document.getElementsByName('territories');
/*below list the value of the selections*/
  var selectedItems="";
    for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
        if(items[i].type=='checkbox' && items[i].checked==true)
            var itemz = selectedItems+=items[i].value+" ";}

    var n = $("input[name=territories]:checked").length;/*Counts 
number of box selected*/
    var salesUrl = 
document.getElementById("salesURL").getAttribute("href");
    var salesID = 
document.getElementById("salesURL").getAttribute('id');

 if( n >= 1 && salesID == "salesURL"){
$("#info").html("Selected only 1" + " " + salesUrl+" "+itemz);
 }else if(n >= 1 && salesID == "nosalesURL"){
 $("#info").html("Go to contact sales");      
       }else{
$("#info").html("none selected");
}
}
```

Here's [a link to where I am building it out](https://codepen.io/herodneydesigns/pen/RzpZGL)!

For some reason when I try to set the condition for more than one selected it gives me the result of the first condition. I want the function to recognize the checkbox and determine if they have a url. if more than one then go to this page. it only one selected and it has a url then go to another page. etc

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want to use the specific URL if 1 checkbox is checked, you can simplify the logic by only looking for that event.  All other scenarios will result in the contact page.  Additionally, `id` should be unique for each element, but they aren't even required here so you should remove them (or make them unique).

I added an additional function for handling the redirects.

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function printChecked() {
    var items = $("input[name=territories]:checked"),
        url = "contact.html";

    if (items.length == 1) {
        var href = items.parent("a").attr("href");
        if ($.trim(href).length > 1) {
            url = href;
        }
    }

    redirect(url);
}

function redirect(url) {
    window.location = url;
}
</script>
```

Comment: that setup gives me some ideas. But, there will be multiple territories with their own pages and others without. So my goal is still to filter if the user chooses more than one territory. If they choose one and it has its own page then it will go to that sales page. if not then it will go to the contact page same goes for if they choose multiple territories even if one of those places have a page it will still send them to the contact page.

Comment: Correct... that is what the code I provided does.  If your goal is to only send the user to a specific URL if only 1 territory is checked, there really isn't a need to collect/filter/analyze anything else.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I arrived at.

```
$( "#territorybtn" ).click(function() {

  var places = $("input[name=territories]:checked");
  var clickTerritory = $("input[name=territories]:checked").val();
  var clickTerritoryUrl = "https://privatecontractor.com/loaction-"+clickTerritory;
  var shortClickTerritoryUrl = clickTerritoryUrl.substr(0, 
clickTerritoryUrl.length-2); 
  var saleID = places.parent("a").attr("class");

  /*below list the value of the selections*/
  var selectedItems="";
     for(var i=0; i<places.length; i++){
    if(places[i].type=='checkbox' && places[i].checked==true)
       var itemz = selectedItems+=places[i].value+" ";}

 /*Conditions*/
  if (places.length == 1 && saleID == "salesURL"){
      window.location = shortClickTerritoryUrl;
  }else if(places.length == 0){
      alert(places.length +" "+ "Choose a Territory");
  }else{
      window.location = "https://privatecontractor.com/contact-sales/?textarea=" + itemz;
  }

});
```

So I am checking to see if the checkboxes are checked and their values. Next, I am looping the values if more than one checkbox is selected so when I parse it to the url for the contact form it will list them in the form.

I placed the condition so that if one checkbox is checked and its parent anchor has the class then it would go to the url created based on its value. If more than one is selected then they will go to contact form with the values added to the url.

For the second part of parsing the checked box values to the url to send to contact form i used a script from this awesome gentleman. https://wplearninglab.com/contact-form-7-get-value-from-url/

Thanks for your help @johnniebenson.